# Is it common to refer to the person steering a ship as 'pilot'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns

According to its [M-W entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilot) (supported by some other dictionaries), a *pilot* (used of a person) can mean, among other things:

> **a** :  one employed to steer a ship :  *helmsman*
>   **b** :  a person who is qualified and usually licensed to conduct a ship into and out of a port or in specified waters
>   **c** :  a person who flies or is qualified to fly an aircraft or spacecraft

I am familiar with the meanings quoted under (b) and (c), but I cannot recall encountering (a). If my understanding is correct, (a) and (b) are quite distinct; in particular, the person referred to by (b) is usually employed by a specific harbour, based on detailed knowledge of its waters, and thus unrelated to the ship in question.

I do not wish to dispute the opinion of multiple dictionaries, I just wonder how common this usage is or whether there is a particular context for it.

Comment: You can't recall encountering the definition meaning ship's pilot probably because you don't have much to do with ships. The reason that listing is first is because it's the original (ships were around before airplanes were) and it's still current.

Comment: It is very common.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks. Granted, I don't (have much to do with ships). Nor with airplanes, for that matter. The question is really about usage; some dictionaries do list the (a) meaning, others don't: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pilot

Comment: **I certainly hope so.** If someone else is steering the ship then we are all in for a bumpy ride.

Answer (score 1):

Pilot was at first the word for the helmsman of a boat and then transferred to the pilot of an aeroplane. See [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pilot&searchmode=none).

Comment: Thank you. I did look at the etymology before asking, and I do not dispute it. What bothers me a bit is current or recent usage. Hence the question.

Comment: I 'm not sure but I think that pilot for helmsman today is not so common, nevertheless this usage is known.

Comment: *Ship pilot, pilot of a ship*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pilot+of+a+ship%2Cship++pilot&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpilot%20of%20a%20ship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cship%20pilot%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks. But can this text search distinguish between (a) and (b)?

Comment: According to Webster : ***Pilot***: 1) (Archaic) helmsman.
2) a person licensed to direct ships into or out of a harbor or through difficult waters. http://www.yourdictionary.com/pilot